# How to fetch Open Weather Map Api

Tags: javascript, html, api, postman, weather-api

My Open Weather Map API working fine on Postman but I'm getting errors while fetching it on the browser.

[Postman ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpdgt.png)

```
//fetching weather api
    async getWeather() {
        console.log("efsfs");
        const response = await fetch('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=3f071776be6f7ccd417bfb1da2910---');
        const responseData = await response.json();

        return responseData;
    }
```

```
//Using it
weather.getWeather()
    .then(results => {
        console.log(results)
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

```
//Error
weather.js:11 GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=3f071776be6f7ccd417bfb1da2910859 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: You've left the `https://` off the beginning of the URL, so it's a relative URL and resolved relative to the document the call is being made from. Just put `https://` in front of `api.openweathermap.org` in your call to `fetch`. (It looks like Postman might do that for you, which seems odd to me; if I were writing it, it would at least update the URL when fixing that for you.)

Comment: But also note that your code is falling prey to the `fetch` footgun [I describe here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html): Before calling `json`, you should check `response.ok` to see whether the HTTP response is a success response. `fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks a lot man, much appreciated. Yes I do check the response status but forget to add here.